# Animation chart in R displaying color code instead of the date

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataset here,

```
> dput(data2)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1651795200, 1651795200, 1652400000, 
1652400000, 1653004800, 1653004800, 1653609600, 1653609600, 1654214400, 
1654214400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
Country = c("MYR", "JPY", "MYR", "JPY", "MYR", "JPY", "MYR", 
"JPY", "MYR", "JPY"), Value = c(-4.58032749341578, -11.8566176470588, 
-5.27883238229476, -10.9425785482124, -5.06949191159718, 
-10.00938379731, -4.84618722451869, -9.46424356856266, -5.06949191159718, 
-12.0721271393643)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I have some code to run an animation bar chart

```
 plot1  <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=reorder(Country, -Value), y=Value, fill=Country)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')


 plot1 + coord_flip() + transition_states(Date, transition_length = 2,state_length = 1, wrap = 
 FALSE)  + geom_text(x=1 ,y=-10, family="Times",aes(label=as.character(Date)),size=6, color 
 ="blue") + xlab("Country")
```

The rendered plot looks great except I have a random character appearing after the date is shown.[image]

Comment: For me, the code works well.

Comment: @Isaac, previously my code works too, but after I updated my R to a newer version I got this error. :(

Comment: Maybe you could uninstall and reinstall ggplot2 and gganimate, and see if it works